# AttributeError: module 'pandas.tseries.frequencies' has no attribute 'is_subperiod'

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror

I cannot understand why I am getting this error while trying to use the `is_subperiod` function of the `pandas` import

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.tseries.frequencies.is_subperiod('M', 'Q')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'pandas.tseries.frequencies' has no attribute 'is_subperiod'
```

It's odd since the import works fine and I've also used pandas without any issues in the past.

Comment: what pandas version?  pd.__version__?

Comment: @yoav_aaa 0.24.2

Comment: there is no function is_subperiod on version 0.24.2. uninstall it and install 0.22.0 using pip install pandas==0.22.0.

Comment: now i'm getting this error while trying to do the following import : `import pandas.compat as compat` gives me `AttributeEror: module 'pandas' has no attribute compat`

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 0.23 pandas has moved `is_subperiod` function to `pd._libs.tslibs.frequencies.is_subperiod` (commit [#17746](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/17746))

If you want to use this function both with the older and the newer versions you would probably write something like:

```
import pandas as pd
try:
    _pandas_is_subperiod = pd.tseries.frequencies.is_subperiod
except AttributeError:
    _pandas_is_subperiod = pd._libs.tslibs.frequencies.is_subperiod
_pandas_is_subperiod('M', 'Q')
```